# Magento Different Grand Total and Invoice amount

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

[image: Total on order page]

[image: Invoice]

Please check these 2 images; I am having an issue where Grand Total displays correctly on all pages throughout the site; But when admin sends an invoice to user it does not include some of the items in the invoiced amount.

I need suggestion on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem ; It comes from the generated extension from silksoftware;

If you have similar problem; open the file in this directory

```
 /www/app/code/local/Company/ExtraFee/Model/Order/Invoice/Total
```

and replace this line

```
 $DepositTotal = $order->getDepositTotal();
 if ($DepositTotal&&count($order->getInvoiceCollection())==0) {
```

with

```
$orderDepositTotal= $order->getDepositTotal();
 if ($orderDepositTotal&&count($order->getInvoiceCollection())==0) {
```

:)

Thanks guys for no help :p I ended up debugging it myself and feeling pretty good :p

```
<?php
class Comapny_ExtraFee_Model_Order_Invoice_Total_Deposit
extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice_Total_Abstract
{
    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice $invoice)
    {
    $order=$invoice->getOrder();
    $DepositTotal = $order->getDepositTotal();
    if ($DepositTotal&&count($order->getInvoiceCollection())==0) {
       $invoice->setGrandTotal($invoice->getGrandTotal()+$orderDepositTotal);
       $invoice->setBaseGrandTotal($invoice->getBaseGrandTotal()+$orderDepositTotal);
      }
   return $this;
    }
 }
```